# Find $\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{\mathrm{d}\theta}{(\sin\theta+1)^2}$.

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, trigonometric-integrals

I was trying to solve the following problem from MIT 2006 Integration Bee: $$
\int_{0}^\infty \frac{dx}{\left(x+\sqrt{1+x^2}\right)^2}.
$$ I've managed to reduce this integral to $$
\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{d\theta}{(\sin\theta+1)^2}
$$ using the trigonometric substitution $x=\tan\theta$. From here I don't know how to proceed. I've consulted [symbolab.com](https://www.symbolab.com/). It gave me the answer $2/3$, which is consistent with the answer provided by Integration Bee. In its solution there was this step $$
\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{d\theta}{(\sin\theta+1)^2} = \int_0^1 \frac{2(u^2+1)}{(u^2+2u+1)^2}du.
$$ I couldn't figure out what substitution it used. Any ideas? Thanks for reading my post.

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**1. Computing the original integral.** I guess this is the shortest way to solve the integral: Substituting $x = \sinh t$,

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{(x+\sqrt{1+x^2})^2}
= \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\cosh t \, \mathrm{d}t}{\left(\sinh t + \cosh t\right)^2}
= \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-t} + e^{-3t}}{2} \, \mathrm{d}t
= \frac{2}{3}. $$

**2. What substitution has been used?** Note the [Weierstrass substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution):

$$ u = \tan(\theta/2), \qquad \mathrm{d}\theta = \frac{2\,\mathrm{d}u}{1+u^2}, \qquad \sin\theta = \frac{2u}{1+u^2}, \qquad \cos\theta = \frac{1-u^2}{1+u^2}. $$

Then as $\theta$ runs from $0$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$, $u$ runs from $0$ to $1$. Hence,

$$ \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{\mathrm{d}\theta}{(\sin\theta+1)^2}
= \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{(\frac{2u}{1+u^2} + 1)^2} \cdot \frac{2\,\mathrm{d}u}{1+u^2}. $$

Simplifying the expression gives the desired rational integral.

Comment: $u=\tan(\theta/2)$.... How could I have forgotten this beauty? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Another way:

$$
\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{d\theta}{(1+\sin\theta)^2}=
\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{d\theta}{(1+\cos\theta)^2}=
\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac14\sec^4(\tfrac\theta 2)\,d\theta=
\int_0^{\pi/4}\frac12\sec^4x\,dx=\left.(\frac12\tan x+\frac16\tan^3x)\right\vert_0^{\frac\pi 4}=\frac23.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Integrate by parts
\begin{align}\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{1}{(\sin\theta+1)^2}d\theta
 =&-\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{1}{\sin\theta+1} d\left(\frac{\cos \theta}{\sin\theta+1}\right)\\
=&\  1+\int_{0}^{\pi/2}  \left(\frac{\cos \theta}{\sin\theta+1}\right)^2 d\left(\frac{\cos \theta}{\sin\theta+1}\right) =\frac23
\end{align}